# Why is my variable returning 'false' when using an && operator

Tags: javascript

I am learning basic conditionals and i'm not 100% sure on why the && in this case is returning 'false' in console.

Is it because the variable is not both 0 and 1.

Thank you in advance,

```
let i = 1;

if (i == 0 && i == 1) {
  console.log('true');
} else {
  console.log('false');
}
```

I was expecting true.

Even if I set `var i = 01;` it still shows false.

I just need a simple explanation why to get it clear in my head :)

Comment: How is `i` both zero *and* one *at the same time*?

Comment: Read it out loud. `If i is equal to zero AND i is equal to one.` Are you confusing AND for OR?

Comment: Perhaps you were looking for the `||` operator?  "And" and "or" are very different things.

Comment: You want `||`, logical OR.

Comment: So @epascarello what you're saying is that it is not possible hence returning false? 

So even if:

`var i = 01`

It's still impossible for `i` to equal both 0 and 1?

Comment: The value `01` means octal 1, it is equals to `1`. There are many representations of `1` - `1`, `01`, `0x01`, `0b00000001` are all the same number just written differently. They are all `1`.

Comment: Your variable is a `number` not a sequence of digits that you happened to write.  1, 01, 001 all are stored as a number equal to `0`.  And it's not a `string` either - "01" would be something very different...

Comment: Is there a use case you're trying to find a solution for? Sharing that, I bet someone can point you to a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is not equal to `0`, therefore the logical AND expression immediately fails; the `else` block is then evaluated, printing `false`.

If you change AND to OR, the code will work as you probably expect.

```js
let i = 1;

if (i == 0 || i == 1) {
  console.log('true');
} else {
  console.log('false');
}
```

For an AND (`&&`) expression to evaluate to `true`, both sides of the expression need to be true.

For an OR (`||`) expression to evaluate to `true`, one or both side(s) of the expression need(s) to be true.

For an XOR (JS does not have a logical XOR operator) expression to evaluate to `true`, one and only one side of the expression needs to be true.

Note: in JS, never attempt to write a number literal with a leading zero. This is because in non-strict mode environments such numbers are interpreted as octal numbers; in strict-mode environments you'll get an error.

Comment: Thank you very much - so grateful for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

How would `i` be able to be two values at once? Even if you did something like `const i = [0, 1]` it would still return `false`.

> `i = 01`

Why would this work? The only way this would work is if you made it a string, split it, assigned it to two different variables, and then ran the check against those two variables.

Perhaps you are thinking of the OR operator `||`.

```js
let i = 1;

if (1 === 0 || i === 1) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Or even use ternaries, which are, from looking at this question, way beyond your skill:

```js
let i = 1;

const j = i === 0 || i === 1 ? true : false;
console.log(j);
```